# Search a string in a CSV file , output all the lines which contain it as table - PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am new to the world of coding and learning PHP these days. For almost one week of research on this issue , I have almost given up on this issue. Hope to get some good insight on it from the experts.

Problem :- I have a CSV file which has information about servers. for Example :

```
ClientId,ProductName,Server,ServerRole,Webserver,DatabaseName
001,abc,Server1,Web,Webserver1,,
001,abc,Server2,Dabatase,,Database1
001,abc,Server3,Application,,,
002,abc,Server4,Web,Webserver2,,
002,abc,Server5,Database,,Database2,
```

I created a HTML page which has a simple html form which takes a server name as an input and invokes the commands written in a page called "search.php". I am able to save the user input from index form to a variable fine . But here is the real problem. I want to search that variable against this CSV file , find the client name ( column 1) related to that server ( which should be matched from column 3 ) and then , print all the lines for that client. For e.g.  if I input "Server3" , I should get the first three lines as output in a table form.

I have used fgetcsv() , fgets() etc. but I dont seem to crack this. So far , the closest I have reached is printing all the lines which contain the input text (and that too not in a table form).  Any help to resolve my problem would be much appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
 $name = $_POST["search"]; 
 echo "You have searched for the server <b>$name</b>";

$output = "";

 $fp = fopen("D:\VMware\DSRM\Servers\Servers.csv", "r");

    // Read file
 $txt = fgets($fp);

 while ( !feof( $fp ) ) {

      // Search for keyword
      if ( stripos( $txt, $name ) !== false ) {
      $output .= $txt.'<br />';
      }

      $txt = fgets($fp);
 }
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: easy import csv to database, because You whant create database in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about regex?

```
$input_lines = file_get_contents("theCSV");
$server = "Server3";
preg_match_all("/(\d+).*(".$server.")(.*)/", $input_lines, $clientid);

preg_match_all("/(". $clientid[1] .".*)/", $input_lines, $output_array);

Var_dump(output_array[1]);
```

In theory this should work :-)

Comment: Thanks Andreas,
But the end user would know only server name so he will input only a servername.  On the basis of servername , I have to find out the client ID and then print all the lines for the client ID.

Comment: Ahh.. ok didn't understand that. Sorry. I will see what I can do.

Comment: Hello Andreas,
I am planning to use mysql database for it. Thanks anyways for your reply. 
Though I didn't try your suggestion but I would definitely try it for sure for my learning. Thanks again for your interest.

Comment: I am working to setup database instead of parsing CSV files. Still workin on it.

Comment: @Dev OK. :-) I have not made that switch yet myself. I use txts for most of my work. But then again, my page is quite basic